# Sort rows in a tab delimited file with numerical order

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I am trying to sort a file which is in the following format

```
ch1 1 209
ch1 23 890
ch3 45 21
ch4 66 12
ch10 12 90
ch10 11 53
```

I am using the command

```
sort -t $"\t" -nk1 filename
```

But in the result, the ch1 comes after ch10

```
ch10 12 90
ch10 11 53
ch1 1 209
ch1 23 890
ch3 45 21
ch4 66 12
```

But I want 1 to come before 10 as it is in numerical value. So can someone suggest what needs to be done?
Expected result:

```
ch1 1 209
ch1 23 890
ch3 45 21
ch4 66 12
ch10 12 90
ch10 11 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the character index where numbers begin in the field in *KEYDEF*. In this case we want to sort on the numeric part of the first field, which begins from the 3rd char, thus `-k1.3n`:

```
$ sort -k1.3n file
ch1     1       209
ch1     23      890
ch3     45      21
ch4     66      12
ch10    11      53
ch10    12      90
```